# How to sum values in a column if values in a row meet a certain criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sum value in a column if he a value in the same row is > x. X is an arbitrary value.

Currently the code sums the same column repeatedly.

I have tried using the ActiveCell.Row function but that depends on which row I choose and I want it to update automatically.

The code below checks if a value at the end of row 3 meet the criteria. If it does it should add the value in cell C3 to the variable ThresholdCount.

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet 'declare your worksheets

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arrivals") 'like this you will refer to it using ws

    Dim cel As Range, unit As Range
    Dim ParcelCount As Long, LowerParcelCount As Long, ThresholdCount As Long

    With ws 'you could also use With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arrivals") if you are not using that sheet anymore
        ParcelCount = .Range("BW8").Value
        LowerParcelCount = .Range("BW5").Value
        ThresholdCount = 0

        For Each cel In .Range("BQ3:BQ78")
            If cel.Value > LowerParcelCount Then
                For Each unit In .Range("C3:C78")
                    ThresholdCount = ThresholdCount + unit.Value
                Next unit
            End If
        Next cel
        .Range("BS16") = ThresholdCount
    End With

End Sub
```

The code should check if a value at the end of row 3 meets the criteria. If it does it should add the value in cell C3 to the variable ThresholdCount. Then it should check if a value at the end of row 4 meets the criteria. If it does it should add the value in cell C4 to the variable ThresholdCount.

What iT does is continue to add the values in Column C if the values in Range BQ3:BQ78 meet the criteria.

Comment: Why VBA when SUMIF will do this.

Comment: It would help if you can post an example of your data or illustrate it in some way. Maybe an image or table of the data? Looking at your c

Comment: @ScottCraner you were actually 100% correct. I tried it your way and it worked just fine. Thanks!